# Integrate $\int\frac{3x^2+1}{(x^2-1)^3}$

Tags: integration

Integrate $$I=\int\frac{3x^2+1}{(x^2-1)^3}$$

---

$$I=\int\frac{3(x^2-1)+4}{(x^2-1)^3}=\int\frac{3}{(x^2-1)^2}+\frac4{(x^2-1)^3}$$
Now I did use integration by parts which actually derives the reduction formula.

---

- Can you suggest a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ \int \frac{3x^2+1}{(x^2-1)^3}dx $$
Using partial fractions, we have
$$ \frac{3x^2+1}{(x-1)^3(x+1)^3}= \frac{\alpha}{(x-1)^3} + \frac{\beta}{(x+1)^3} $$
$$ \frac{3x^2+1}{(x-1)^3(x+1)^3}= \frac{\alpha (x+1)^3+\beta (x-1)^3}{(x-1)^3(x+1)^3} $$
$$ 3x^2+1= \alpha (x+1)^3+\beta (x-1)^3 $$
Let $x=-1$, then
$$ 3(-1)^2+1=\alpha (-1+1)^3+ \beta (-1-1)^3 $$
$$ 4=\alpha (0)+ \beta (-2)^3 $$
$$ 4=-8\beta $$
$$ \beta=-\frac{1}{2} $$
Let $x=1$, then
$$ 3(1)^2+1=\alpha (1+1)^3+ \beta (1-1)^3 $$
$$ 4=8\alpha + \beta (0) $$
$$ 4=8\alpha $$
$$ \alpha=\frac{1}{2} $$
Thus
$$ \int \frac{3x^2+1}{(x^2-1)^3}dx= \frac{1}{2}\int \frac{1}{(x-1)^3}dx - \frac{1}{2}\int \frac{1}{(x+1)^3}dx $$
Can you solve it from here?

Comment: Hermite, right?

Comment: @k170, de facto Partial Fraction Decomposition(http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartialFractionDecomposition.html), has terms like $$\frac\gamma{(x-1)}+\frac\delta{(x-1)^2}$$ etc., right?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee, sure you could simplify the integrands further via partial fraction decomposition but, at this point these integrals can be easily solved via substitution, right?

Answer (score 3):

> *Can you suggest a better way ?*

I would suggest a *different* way: Let $~I(a)=\displaystyle\int\frac{3x^2+1}{x^2+a}dx.~$ Then your integral is a multiple of $I''(-1)$.

Comment: I have no idea about differentiating integrals, maybe you can elaborate your answer?

Comment: @Aditya: The variable with regard to which you differentiate is *a*. *X* basically acts like a constant.

Comment: So how that can be used to evaluate this integral?

Comment: @Aditya: $I(a)$ should be easily solvable. Then differentiate both expressions with regard to *a* twice, and finally replace its value with $-1$.

Comment: got it, but how did you work backwards?

Comment: @Aditya: What do you mean ?

Comment: how did you got this idea

Comment: @Aditya: [Link](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-304-undergraduate-seminar-in-discrete-mathematics-spring-2006/projects/integratnfeynman.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

Let $$\displaystyle I = \int\frac{3x^2+1}{(x^2-1)^3}dx = \int\frac{3x^2+1}{x^{\frac{3}{2}}\cdot \left(x^{\frac{3}{2}}-x^{-\frac{1}{2}}\right)^3}dx$$

So we get $$\displaystyle I = \int\frac{3x^{\frac{1}{2}}+x^{-\frac{3}{2}}}{\left(x^{\frac{3}{2}}-x^{-\frac{1}{2}}\right)^3}dx$$

Now Put $$\displaystyle \left(x^{\frac{3}{2}}-x^{-\frac{1}{2}}\right) = t\;,$$ Then $$\displaystyle \left(\frac{3}{2}x^{\frac{1}{2}}+\frac{1}{2}x^{-\frac{-3}{2}}\right)=dt$$

So we get $$\displaystyle \left(3x^{\frac{1}{2}}+x^{-\frac{3}{2}}\right)dx = 2dt$$

So we get $$\displaystyle I = 2\int\frac{1}{t^3}dt = -\frac{1}{t^2}+\mathcal{C} = -\frac{1}{\left(x^{\frac{3}{2}}-x^{-\frac{1}{2}}\right)^2}+\mathcal{C}$$

So we get $$\displaystyle I = \int\frac{3x^2+1}{(x^2-1)^3}dx = -\left[\frac{x}{(x^2-1)^2} \right]+\mathcal{C}$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $$\displaystyle I = \int\frac{3x^2+1}{(x^2-1)^3}dx = \int\frac{3x^2+1}{(x-1)^2(x+1)^3}dx = \frac{1}{2}\int\frac{(x+1)^3-(x-1)^3}{(x-1)^3(x+1)^3}dx$$

So we get $$\displaystyle I = \frac{1}{2}\int \left[\frac{1}{(x-1)^3}-\frac{1}{(x+1)^3}\right]dx = \frac{1}{4}\left[-\frac{1}{(x-1)^2}+\frac{1}{(x+1)^2}\right]+\mathcal{C}$$

So we get $$\displaystyle I = \int\frac{3x^2+1}{(x^2-1)^3}dx = -\frac{x}{(x^2-1)^2}+\mathcal{C}$$